# Post JSON and File with PHP CURL

Tags: php, json, box-api

Unlike many other questions, I am looking to post Json *and* a file content to the Box API.

I am sending the following as the `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` fields:

```
Array
(
    [attributes] => {"name":"API Upload.ods","parent":{"id":"1234567"}}
    [file_contents] => CURLFile Object
        (
            [name] => /var/www/html/Sample_for_box.ods
            [mime] => 
            [postname] => 
        )

)
```

With the `Content-Type: multipart/form-data` along with the `Bearer token`.

What I get back from Box is:

`Invalid value 'd_1234567'. 'parent' with value 'd_1234567' not found`

It looks like PHP is doing something wierd with the inner JSON. Remove the parent element and I get an error saying the element is missing! Why is this content not getting through to Box?

Comment: Take a look at this repo to see how they do this: https://github.com/linkstreet/box-sdk

Comment: Thanks - appear to use Guzzle rather than pure PHP